# Database table design and relationship

Tags: sql, database, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

I have one table lets say TBL1 for registering the users and it contains close to 10 columns in it.I am adding all the new users to this table.Now for doing login for those users, should I point my DAO to this TBL1 for validating the users or I need to have separate table which will deal with login part.

Just a general doubt,whats the best way to maintain information about new user registration and validating users using register information.How do you register and allow users to login to your app ? are both insert and read happens from single table or from different tables ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the logic I would use:

1. I would register the NEW user in the registration table like you described above
2. When they fill out their username n password to login, I would first check for existence of that user in the registration table or TBL1. If they exist, then use their username and hashed password they used when they first registered from TBL1 or registration table to validate against their username and password on the client side i.e in browser window. 
   If those two don't match, i.e if the infos from the registration table doesn't match that provided in the login form on the client side, then you know they entered a wrong username or password.

To answer your question, you do NOT need a separate table for login users if you already have a registration table. You could use that registration table to do the validation when they go to log in. You can do both an INSERT and a READ to that same registration table, NO NEED for two tables there. Hope that helps you!

Comment: I think I did the same thing for earlier project, I had everything in one table,but later on I realised that it was getting fat.I want tables to serve there purpose.Register should have  register information and should be used only for registering purpose and login should validate logins and probably change pw.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirement of application and security concerns. Of course creating a separate table for log in information is good practice.

If you have separate table for USERNAME and PASSWORD you can set limited rights on it. So only a specific part of your application can access it. And you can allow other registration details to be accessed more frequently if you need.

You might have some service that authenticate the user. So you can give access to only authentication and resetting password services for your log in table.

Even if you need to add or change something in your registration details it does not affect your authentication process at all.

Comment: Thanks Mak , I think I want to have separate table for login.What are different ways to move data to login table from register table.My flow is something like allow user to register, insert data in table with flag indicator, send the email and once email is validated, turn the flag on in register table.Now once flag is turned on, I need to move user id/pw to login table and validate users from login table. For every insert in register table, probably I want to do this.

Comment: Will recommend it to do it via sql procedure or you want me to do insert via code on server side, there is some gotcha doing it via code, as it might expose pw components.Any suggestions ?

Comment: I did not understand why you want to store log in data in REGISTER table and then move to LOGIN table. Don't you think there would be redundant data in REGISTER and LOGIN talbes?? What is wrong as if you store id/pwd in LOGIN table when registered, and also have varified flag in login table. If you don't want to maintain flag in login table then you can do it either way as you told. If you are storing password hash then I do not think there would be exposing issue.

Comment: makes sense Mak, Let me think over this and come back.Seems like something is not right about requirement.All we know that we need 2 different tables one for register and another for login.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Requirement and many factors of application:

Case 1: Requirement is small database having 10 tables, then you can maintain the login and registration information in the single table - TBL1.

Case 2: Requirement is big having say more than 10-20 tables, then it is good to use Normalized Level and so Create 2 different tables for registration and login and mapped with primary key.